# group parts of a string into an array element

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string... abcdefghi
and I want to use regex to load every elemnent into an array but I want to be able to stick anything connected by plus sign into the same element... how to do that?

```
var mystring = "abc+d+efghi"

output array ["a","b","cde","f","g","h","i"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
var re = /([^+])(?:\+[^+])*/g;
var str = 'abcd+e+fghi';
var a = str.match(re).map(function (s) { return s.replace(/\+/g, ''); });
console.log(a);
```

The value of `a[3]` should now be 'def'.
http://jsfiddle.net/rbFwR/2

Comment: I threw some alerts in there and the plus sign is still there? alert(s.match(/([^+])(?:\+[^+])*/g));;;; 

alert(s.replace(/\+/g, ''));  alert(s[4]);;;

Comment: I didn't assign the result back to `s`, just dumped it to the console. I can see now that my reuse of the `s` name was confusing.  Updated.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without console.log?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this expression, to produce [a][b][c+d+e][f][g][h][i].

```
mystring.split ("(.\+)*.")
```

Next, replace any + characters with empty on the resulting list.

Comment: How would you replace any + characters with empty on the resulting list.

Answer (score -2):

```
mystring.split("\\+")
```

Click [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for more information.

Comment: This would give ['abc','d','efghi']

Comment: won't that just split it into 3 sections?

Comment: The answer for this should have 7 array elements